# PrimeFaces File Upload not working on Apple IOS 11.4.1

Tags: ios, file-upload, primefaces

File upload is not working on Ipad version 11.4.1 but working on 8.4.1 i did not test other versions. This file upload working from 2 years i did not face any problem. I am not able to save forms with file upload component from iphone and ipad.
Primefaces Version 6.0

Is there anyone face like this problem ?

My example code;

```
<h:form id="test" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <p:fileUpload  
         mode="advanced" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{testManagedBean.handleFileUpload}">
        <f:attribute name="item" value="#{item}" />
    </p:fileUpload>
    <h:commandButton id="Save"  
        action="#{testManagedBean.upload}"
        value="Test">
        <f:ajax execute="@all" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This is my managedbean;

```
@ManagedBean ( name = "testManagedBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4426815554605967048L;

private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() {
    if(file != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
    else
    {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("No file Selected");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = ( HttpServletRequest ) context.getExternalContext().getRequest ();

    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}

}
```

Giving this error msg.

```
    Jul 25, 2018 6:04:36 PM org.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest parseRequest
SEVERE: Error in parsing fileupload request
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at org.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:57)
at org.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:51)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.harmony.ict.workorder.servlets.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.harmony.ict.workorder.servlets.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the forums I think you will have to create an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.